# How to use Action Bar with Theme_NoTitleBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How can I enable the Action Bar selectively when a) I'm running on a large screen, and b) running Honeycomb or later?

I have an app that needs as much screen real-estate as possible on small devices, so I use android theme `Theme_NoTitleBar` to get rid of the title bar. On post-3.x systems this also removes the action bar which is just what I want.

But on Tablets, I would like to have the action bar. My code looks like this (simplified):

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;

public class ActionBarTest extends Activity {

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
            getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

However, the `requestFeature()` call is having no effect.

One more twist: I still need to support Android 2.x devices.

Comment: You need to use `Toolbar`. Here's the example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31901651/3922207 And don't forget to set the app theme via manifest.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using **android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar** and a no action bar theme. The **Toolbar** is more customizable, and is backward compatible. In addition, it's a view, so you can change it's visibility very easily.
Don't forget you can also provide alternative layouts using classifiers like api level and screen size (among many others). You can include the toolbar in some of them, and not others, depending on what you need to achieve.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: You mean choose a theme that has an action bar and turn it off later?

Comment: I think you might be able to set a theme

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a simple way to fix it using alternative resources.

**res/values/themes.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="CalcTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar" />
  ...
</resource>
```

**res/values-xlarge-v11:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="CalcTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo" />
</resources>
```

It did the job perfectly.

I'll leave the question open for a little while longer though. I'm still wondering why `requestFeature()` didn't work. It seems that if you have Holo theme, you get an action bar, and if you don't have Holo theme you *can't* get an action bar, so what does `requestFeature()` actually do?